# Creating a Sequence with positive and negative numbers in R

Tags: r, sequence

I have been trying to create a function for the sequence of following series:

1,-2,-3, 4, 5, 6, -7 ,-8, -9, -10........n  (1 positive, 2 negatives, 3 positives, 4 negatives … and goes on up to n).

Creating a non-negative  sequence is quite easy, but these negative terms are testing me.

If anyone can help me over this

Comment: Perhaps you can tweak this `(1:10)*(-1)^(rep(1:4, 1:4) - 1)`

Comment: eee Ugly `f <- function(N) (1:N)*(-1)^(rep(1:N,1:N) - 1)[1:N]`

Comment: @user20650 Yours is fantastic. Just need to keep in a function

Comment: That's a fun question! Do you think you could edit your question with a synthetic solution combining our propositions?

Comment: @VincentGuillemot And what is that proposition???

Comment: Something like `f <- function(n) (1:n)*(-1)^( ceiling(sqrt(2*(1:n) + 0.25) - 0.5) -1)` : it combines @user20650 and @Will Beason's propositions...

Comment: @VincentGuillemot Well. My take on this is they are individually good and best of all. Although doesn't have much of difference.

Comment: Fair enough. Vectorizing would allow you to have a very efficient and fast function. Which is useful if you want n to be big.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to do this.

```
myfun <- function(n) {
  myvec <- integer(n)
  for (i in seq_len(n)) {
    curtri <- ceiling(sqrt(i*2 + 0.25) - 0.5)
    myvec[i] <- i * (-1)^(curtri + 1)
  }
  return(myvec)
}

myfun(10)
 [1]   1  -2  -3   4   5   6  -7  -8  -9 -10
```

It takes advantage of the fact that you can find which triangular number you are at with `sqrt(i*2 + 0.25) - 0.5`. By applying even to non triangular numbers, we can determine the index of the next triangular number, and use that as the exponent for `-1`.

There's probably a better way, though.

Comment: Works well, but slow. Probably all those `ceiling` calls.

Answer (score 3):

There are so many ways to do this!

For example:

```
n <- 30
a <- 1:n
m <- ceiling(uniroot(function(x, N) x*(x+1)/2 - N, N=n, interval=c(0, n))$root)
b <- 2*( ((rep(1:m,1:m))[1:n] %% 2 == 1) - 0.5)
a*b
```

Comment: I was too lazy to compute the formula given by @Will Beason

Answer (score 2):

```
n <- 20
k <- n
m <- do.call(cbind, rep(list(c((-1)^(seq_len(k)+1))),k))
m[upper.tri(m)] <- 0
sign <- t(m)[t(m) != 0]

seq_len(n) * sign[seq_len(n)]
#[1]   1  -2  -3   4   5   6  -7  -8  -9 -10  11  12  13  14  15 -16 -17 -18 -19 -20
```

The value for `k` is wastefully high, but I'm too tired to do the maths and find a lower bound. I leave that to you.

Comment: To minimize, set `k <- ceiling(sqrt(2*n + 0.25) - 0.5)`. Just the ceiling of the inverse triangle number function.

Comment: @1089 I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @Roland Pardon. Actually I was writing for someone else. Yours is right too.

Answer (score 2):

For an easy to understand loop solution:

```
myfn = function(n){
    nn = 1:n
    x=1; i=0; j=1;
    while(TRUE){
        if(x==-1) for(k in j:(j+i)) { nn[k] = x*nn[k]; }
        x = x*(-1)
        i = i+1
        j = j+i
        if(j>n) break
    }
    nn[1:n]
}

> for(i in 1:20) print(myfn(i))
[1] 1
[1]  1 -2
[1]  1 -2 -3
[1]  1 -2 -3  4
[1]  1 -2 -3  4  5
[1]  1 -2 -3  4  5  6
[1]  1 -2 -3  4  5  6 -7
[1]  1 -2 -3  4  5  6 -7 -8
[1]  1 -2 -3  4  5  6 -7 -8 -9
 [1]   1  -2  -3   4   5   6  -7  -8  -9 -10
 [1]   1  -2  -3   4   5   6  -7  -8  -9 -10  11
 [1]   1  -2  -3   4   5   6  -7  -8  -9 -10  11  12
 [1]   1  -2  -3   4   5   6  -7  -8  -9 -10  11  12  13
 [1]   1  -2  -3   4   5   6  -7  -8  -9 -10  11  12  13  14
 [1]   1  -2  -3   4   5   6  -7  -8  -9 -10  11  12  13  14  15
 [1]   1  -2  -3   4   5   6  -7  -8  -9 -10  11  12  13  14  15 -16
 [1]   1  -2  -3   4   5   6  -7  -8  -9 -10  11  12  13  14  15 -16 -17
 [1]   1  -2  -3   4   5   6  -7  -8  -9 -10  11  12  13  14  15 -16 -17 -18
 [1]   1  -2  -3   4   5   6  -7  -8  -9 -10  11  12  13  14  15 -16 -17 -18 -19
 [1]   1  -2  -3   4   5   6  -7  -8  -9 -10  11  12  13  14  15 -16 -17 -18 -19 -20
```

Comment: It is working now. Easy to understand solutions are easy to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Although perhaps not the most elegant but I believe this will provide what you want.

```
pos_neg_seq <- function(n){
  s= seq((n*(n+1)/2))

  loc <-1
  for(i in 1:n){
    if(i %% 2 == 0){
      s[loc:(loc+i-1)] <- sapply(s[loc:(loc+i-1)], FUN = function(x) -x)
    }
    loc <- loc + i
  }
  return(s)
}

pos_neg_seq(4)
[1]   1  -2  -3   4   5   6  -7  -8  -9 -10
```

Another possible way for a specific length vector using the equation Vincent provided.

```
pos_neg_seq <- function(n){
  nn <- seq(n)
  m = ceiling(uniroot(function(x, N) x*(x+1)/2 - N, N=n, interval=c(0, n))$root)

  vec <- 1
  for(i in 2:m){
    vec <- append(vec, ifelse(rep(i%%2==0, i), rep(-1, i), rep(1, i)))
  }

  return(nn*vec[1:n])
}

pos_neg_seq(7)
[1]  1 -2 -3  4  5  6 -7
```

Comment: If you are passing 4 as argument it should print only 1, -2, -3, 4. Right??

Comment: @1089, the `s = seq((n*(n+1)/2))` provides the initial sequence that will have the signs altered at the interval desired. I assumed you wanted the sequence dependent on `n`.

Comment: Sorry, If i am not clear. But i wanted to print the what is passed in argument in the positive and negative order. what i have written in the previous comment.

Comment: @1089, I see, no this function will not provide a sequence of a specified length (e.g. 1, -2, -3, 4).  The way the question was phrased made me think you wanted a sequence dependent on `n` so it would always create a sequence of 'completed signs' if you will.  The accepted answer is far more generalizable for that scenario.

Comment: Oh that's my mistake. But i see everyone else understood well. Because they have answered in the regards i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I can't even tell which is better, so a time-challenge will follow.  Here's mine:

```
pmfoo<-10
curtri <- ceiling(sqrt(pmfoo*2 + 0.25) - 0.5)
pmbar<-integer()
for(j in 1:(curtri)) pmbar<-c(pmbar,rep( (-1)^(j-1),j))
pmbar*1:pmfoo
[1]   1  -2  -3   4   5   6  -7  -8  -9 -10
```

Here are time trials for the "better-looking" (biased opinion :-) ) functions:

```
Rgames> x <-1e5
Rgames> microbenchmark(cgw(x),mso(x),willb(x),times=5)
Unit: milliseconds
     expr       min        lq    median        uq       max
   cgw(x)  46.61292  47.50237  48.40807  48.42774  52.02789
   mso(x)  88.63360  97.72099  97.84286  99.00899 101.57643
 willb(x) 281.88658 285.76896 286.92397 290.83628 294.96882
 neval
     5
     5
     5
```

I left Roland's out 'cause it's a major memory hog :-(

Run again with mso's modified code:

```
 microbenchmark(cgw(x),mso(x),willb(x),newmso(x),times=5)
Unit: milliseconds
      expr       min        lq    median        uq       max
    cgw(x)  51.25860  51.29666  56.21858  58.07190  61.32610
    mso(x)  88.08966  89.17924  90.23504  93.28527  95.74666
  willb(x) 280.68967 287.53589 287.81086 288.31673 292.60749
 newmso(x)  71.53771  72.53193  72.68844  72.99419  79.21480
 neval
     5
     5
     5
     5
```

Comment: I have altered my code and removed 'if' test from the 'for' loop. It may result in major time improvement. Can you please try and post its result.

Comment: @mso New version is better but I still win :-)

Comment: Yes. Congratulations.